# Why don't I have settings for F# syntax colors in VS 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, f#, visual-studio-2017

I was using VS 2015 and by going to `Tools/Options/Fonts and Colors/Show Settings for: Text Editor` I could scroll down and find quite a few F# items like `F# Escaped Characters`, `F# Functions / Methods`, etc. that I could use to change colors and fonts of F# related text in the editor.

In VS 2017 these F# related items are no longer there.

I installed the same settings I had in VS 2015 (a .vssettings file).

I also have ColorThemeEditor.vsix and FSharpPowerTools.vsix installed. (Or at least when I double-click on these files I get a message that they are already installed)

Would someone know how to get these F# items into the `Fonts and Colors` settings for the editor?

Comment: The stock VS2017 was frozen some time ago. Can you try and install the [latest F# vsix](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/wiki/Using-CI-Builds).

Comment: F# Power Tools does not exist for VS 2017; its features have been integrated into the VS F# Tools. The message you are getting probably refers to it being installed in VS 2015.

Comment: @s952163 - I tried that and now I cannot open my existing projects or create new ones. When I try to create a new project I get the message: `'C:\Users\ ... \ConsoleApplication3.fsproj' cannot be opened because its project type (.fsproj) is not supported by this version of the application. To open it, please use a version that supports this type of project.`

Comment: @Soldalma - That `.fsproj` error is a bug that I've seen people talking about on one of the F#-related Github bug trackers. Might be related to https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/2400, where Phillip Carter said "The Visual F# Tools project system does not support F# on .NET Core: The new .fsproj file does not load in VS...". Or it might be related to https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/2362 or https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/2340, though those seem less likely to be the specific issue you're facing.

Comment: @Soldalma, BTW, which VS 2017 are you using? A release candidate, or the official release that just came out less than 24 hours ago? If it's a release candidate, try the official release and see if that bug was fixed or not.

Comment: @rmunn - The official release that came out today. I am reinstalling it right now.

Comment: @Soldalma let me install this, also feel free to drop by [F# Slack](http://foundation.fsharp.org/join) as troubleshooting installs can get quite tricky.

Comment: @s952163 - I reinstalled and everything is fine. Except that I still don't have the F# items and Tools/Options/Fonts and Colors/Text Editor/Display Items.

Comment: @Soldalma do you mean there's no syntax coloring whatsoever or that you cannot change the colors (e.g. to neon-pink for mutables and lime-green for DUs... etc.) It's ca. 4GB, will take me  a while to d/l and install.

Comment: @s952163 - There is syntax coloring. Keywords like let, type, module, open are lime green, comments are a darker green, the names I gave to types I created are violet and so are F#'s types like string or Dictionary. Values, including functions, are white, strings between quotes like "Hello" are brick-colored. So there is syntax coloring, it is just that I was used to changing it.

Comment: @Soldalma Yeah, it seems so. There are a few settings in `Tools | Options | Environment | Fonts and Colors` that begin with F#, you can change those.  I assume it will get better with an Update.

Comment: @s952163 So you see those settings in your VS 2017 installation (the one released today)?

Comment: I just installed the release version, and checked the F# language support box in the installer, and I do *not* see any `Fonts and Colors` settings whose names begin with F#. That seems to be an omission, which should probably be filed as a bug in the visualfsharp issue tracker since I doubt it was intended behavior.

Comment: @rmunn  yes, I can see those settings. Have you installed the latest vsix with F# support?

Comment: @s952163 - No, I hadn't. I had been under the impression that that was what would be packaged with the official installer, but apparently that didn't happen? The copy of Visual F# Tools that shows up in my fresh install of VS 2017 is version `15.4.1.17022502`.

Comment: @rmunn dunno, that seems like official VS numbering, and could be old as code freeze was quite some time ago, but don't take my word for it. It's confusing to say the least. :-(

Comment: From the last number of the version, I'd guess that it was build on Feb. 25, 2017 -- but that's just a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are actually still there. For instance, if you want to change `keyword` or `operator` color just find keyword and operator and change the color. I understand that you want to see `F# keyword` in the list but it changed.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously we care about our colors and ligatures and other productivity boosting settings :-). I promised myself to wait until Update 3 at least but here it goes:

As VFPT is being folded into VS proper some of the settings are missing and less obvious than in VS2015, however in VS2017 this exists:

[image]

There are also some settings under User Types.

Now this may depend on having the latest [F# Extensions installed](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/wiki/Using-CI-Builds) and/or updated.

[image]

Comment: I have Visual F# Tools installed and there are no Updates available. Still the F# items displayed in your screen snapshot do not show in my VS 2017 installation. (They do show in VS 2015).

Comment: where did u get the F# Tools from @Soldalma?

Comment: I had already installed `FSharpVSPowerTools.vsix` with VS 2015. When I double-clicked on it trying to install it for VS 2017 I got the message `This extension is already installed to all applicable products.` After I noticed the absence of the F# entries I also downloaded and installed `FSharp_Bundle.exe` and `FSharp_BundleLP.exe` but that did not help either.

Comment: @Soldalma those VS PowerTools are only for VS2015. That functionality was moved inside VS. For VS2017 Can you download and install the vsix package referenced [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/wiki/Using-CI-Builds). Or maybe wait a day or two until better F# Tooling comes out.

Comment: I already tried to install `VisualFSharpOpenSource.vsix` and had to uninstall and reinstall VS 2017. I can live with the syntax highlighted with the current colors, so I will wait. And I am having other problems with VS 2017. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: @Soldalma I agree, this is all pretty experimental, so prob it's better to wait for the official F# Tools updates. For example Alt+Enter also doesn't work, neither does Send to FSI Interactive.

Comment: Alt+Enter also does not work for me but right-click on code then Execute in Interactive does work.

Comment: @Soldalma yes. Regarding the coloring, and the Rename error, it's definitely because of the stock F# Tools. I uninstalled F# Tools, then reinstalled and basically got your situation with the syntax colors. Re: Send to FSI Interactive, I meant for References (that's present in the stock Tools, but not I the OpenSource.visx). Yes, manually doing selection Execute in Interactive works. Also, I believe installing VS2017 overwrote some user settings for VS2015.

Comment: But to leave a positive comment as well, the Navigation Bar, code fix, and tooltips are really great in VS2017.